# Winforms - Make 2 controls load at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, ubuntu, mono

I have an usercontrol which acts as a container for 2 more user controls. One of the control invoves drawing thumbnail in an array like a table with images. Other one is like a vertical toolbar with few images. When I add the container control to the form, the second control loads first while the first one with images loads noticebly slow. Is there a way to make them both instantly and at the same time?

Comment: Is it possible to load the images before you show the controls?

Comment: I am making them paint in the onpaint override. Where else can I do that?

Comment: Something is slowing it down. Use the debugger or a `Stopwatch` to measure time.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I did that. Drawing text on the control takes a long time. It takes about 150ms and painting images takes 20ms.

Comment: Can you add some code? How do you paint etc.